# Bronica ETRSi not winding film/firing shutter correctly

Tags: film, repair, shutter, medium-format

I've recently acquired a Bronica ETRSi and I'm having issues with it (1) Winding on the film and (2) Firing the shutter. I'm wondering if anyone might have any suggestions.

There are 2 levers on the side that control double exposure and mirror lockup, to which I have tried the 4 permutations in order to try getting the shutter to fire etc.

| Photo (click to enlarge) | Double Exposure | Mirror Lockup | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | ACTIVE | ACTIVE | Cranks and locks, mirror locks up, shutter fires - No film advance based on window & no spool spin - All as expected |
| [image] | ACTIVE | INACTIVE | Cranks and locks, no mirror lockup, shutter fires - No film advance mased on window & no spool spin - All as expected |
| [image] | INACTIVE | ACTIVE | Cranks and locks, mirror locks up, shutter fires - No film advance based on window & spool spins - Should see film advance |
| [image] | INACTIVE | INACTIVE | Cranks but does not lock - Normal initial wind and then loose wind after 2 rotations hutting a bump each other loose rotation - spool spins - No film advance - Shutter does not fire |

I noted that the manual spool winder on the film does indeed spin when I am spinning the film/shutter winder, proving that the double exposure switch does move the geared wheel into the correct positions.

FYI - I checked that everything was in the right configuration during the test. Film loaded, lens attached, dark slide removed, shutter button lock disengaged etc

Comment: Was there film in the camera during the tests ?

Comment: How does the manual describe the camera’s operation?

Comment: Have you contacted the seller?

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens everything was as described in the manual for correct operation. Film loaded, dark slide removed, lens attached and shutter button lock disangaged.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens I found the problem/solution - See below

Comment: I am glad you figured it out. I keep a practice roll of 120 just because I know I will want to open up the back of a new camera.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer... The film was fully advanced and off the initial spool. The constant spinning and "bump" I felt must have been the tail of the end of the roll hitting the other spool.

I got into this situation due to my hesitation and experimentation with loading/going through my first film in this camera.

I wasn't sure if I'd loaded things correctly the first time so I did open the back, check things were advancing and then closing it back up. This led to the film counter resetting itself, so I didn't really know where I was on the film. Plus I'd just come from shooting a lot of 35mm so silly me, forgot it was only 15 frames...

I chalked this roll up to being a waste and to just get the action of using the camera down, so I reversed the film and **ran it back through and everything worked perfectly as expected**.

I'm not sure if I've exposed the middle of the film, so I'm going to go back through again the correct way and then I should have the operation down to a fine art :D